# uitextview keyboard appear above uitoolbar

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I have a uitoolbar at bottom of my main view. I also have a uitextview at top of my view. when tapped on the textview to start editing I want the keyboard to appear from above the toolbar, not covering the tool bar. I want to know how I can do that also I don't want it to be animated.

I have one more question, when the keyboard appears is it possible to put another view in front of it?

thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the former. The keyboard is in a different window and so doens't interact with the views in your window. Apple doesn't provide any public access to the keyboard window.

As to the latter, putting a view in front of it, you might be able to something like that by creating another window but I've not seen anyone do it and not sure what it would do to the keyboard events, etc.